# Select distinct properties of object with LINQ

Tags: linq, select, dictionary, distinct

How could i improve this code:

```
Dim count As Integer = 0
Dim myDictionary As Dictionary(Of Long, List(Of Proposal)) = list.GroupBy(Function(x) x.BankAccountId).ToDictionary(Function(g) g.Key, Function(a) a.ToList)

For Each bAccId As Long In myDictionary.Keys
    Dim currencies As Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Proposal)) = myDictionary(bAccId).GroupBy(Function(x) x.Currency).ToDictionary(Function(g) g.Key, Function(a) a.ToList)

    For Each c As String In currencies.Keys
        Dim execDates2 As Dictionary(Of Date, List(Of Proposal)) = currencies(c).GroupBy(Function(x) x.ExecutionTime).ToDictionary(Function(g) g.Key, Function(a) a.ToList)
        count += execDates2.Keys.Count
    Next
Next
```

Comment: This isn't a code improvement site. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I would like to obtain a distinct combination of x.BankAccountId, x.ExecutionDate, x.Currency from a list, with only one query. I tried different combinations of groupBy, Select, distinct, and couldn't make it.

Comment: If your are confident that the current code works, it would be a question for [codereview.se]. However, with your comment above it doesn't sound like the code works in the way you want it.

Comment: It does, i get the desired combination through the "count" variable, but i would like something like list.groupby().distinct().tolist.count, and i can't figure it out how.